# Dump core file with shared memory included of running process in docker

Tags: linux, docker, coredump

We have a process running with shared memory used, and using the technique described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35478378/1256392), we can successfully dump a core file with shared memory included when the process runs on host machine. However the technique does not work when the process runs in docker.

We change the value of `/proc/<pid>/coredump_filter` to `0xffff` pragmatically in our process:

```
char cmd[256];
snprintf(cmd, sizeof(cmd), "echo 0xFFFF > /proc/%d/coredump_filter", getpid());
system(cmd);
```

On host machine it successfully changes to `000001ff`, but in docker the value remains `00000033`.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just open `/proc/self/coredump_filter` in your process and write whatever you want there?

Comment: @Kit. Yeah, you're right, with the `open/write` approach it works. However, I'm still curious why the `system` approach does not work.